# Why tochesBegan is not working in UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, touchesbegan

i am facing the problem  tapping on the table view my code was not working....

**Why tochesBegan was not working in UITableView ?**

i used table header as my custom view on that i need to recognize the tapping in the header...

**How do i recognize the tapping in the table view header?**

i reffed **developer.apple** the site shows like that....

Thanks in advance....

Spynet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at this sample : http://developer.casgrain.com/?p=100

i think this might solve your trouble =)